# Using Marionette Compositeview within a Layout region

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm creating a portfolio type site. The project page shows general information about the project and a gallery.

I've split it up, so the project page is a Marionette Layout. This layout renders information about the project within its own template and has a gallery region. I want to add a gallery composite view to this region. This will have a large image and a list of thumbnails.

**Project Layout**

```
ProjectView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend
    template: '#ProjectView'
    className: 'project__item'

    events: {
        'click .close-project': 'closeProject'
        'click #next': 'navigateProject'
        'click #prev': 'navigateProject'
    }

    regions: {
        gallery: ".left"
    }

    initialize: ->
        @galleryCollection = new GalleryCollection @model.get('images')

    onRender: ->
        @galleryView = new GalleryCompositeView { model: @model, collection: @galleryCollection }
        @gallery.show @galleryView
```

**Gallery CompositeView**

```
GalleryCompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend
    template: '#gallery__composite'
    itemView: GalleryItemView
    itemViewContainer: '.thumbs'
    className: 'project__gallery'

    initialize: ->
        console.log 'new GalleryCompositeView'
```

**Gallery Item View**

```
GalleryItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
    tagName: 'li'
    className: 'gallery__item'

    template: _.template '''
        <div class="loading">LOADING<span class="icon-loading"></span></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
    '''

    initialize: ->
        console.log 'new GalleryItemView'
```

When I pass both the model and the collection to the composite view I get the error below, but when I pass just the model, it renders fine just without the thumbs. I can't see anything wrong with how I have setup my composite view.

Its strange that GalleryCompositeView is being initialised twice.

Any direction would be appreciated, thanks.

[image: Imgur]

**Edit**
Turns out there where two issues, thanks daivd for pointing out the collection issue, I was just passing in an array or image paths. This was my fix

```
        images = []
        _.each @model.get('images'), ( el ) -> images.push { src: el }
        @galleryCollection = new GalleryCollection images
```

The second error was declaring my CompositeView gallery view in my code before the thumb nail views. Changing the order fixed everything. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the data in your collection. Dump `@model.get('images')` and `@galleryCollection` (from the `initialize` method) to the console and make sure all of the contained models have an `src` property.